# Qt 4.8.4 - generating click error - coordinates used by QPoint

Tags: c++, qt, casting, click

I am working on an embedded linux project using Qt 4.8.4 and I want to generate click to a given position.

First I will give you a sum-up of my code and then explains the problem.

main.cpp : Declare a new QApplication

```
`int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    main_app = new QApplication( argc, argv ) ;
    [....]
}`
```

mainwindow.h : header of the mainwindow

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
     Q_OBJECT

    public :

     void generate_click( int coord_x, int coord_y ) ;

    [...]
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp: definition of my function

```
    void MainWindow::generate_click(int x, int y)
    {


        printf("Enter generate_click : (%d/%d)\n", x, y) ;

        QPoint _pos_click( x, y ) ;
        QWidget *receiver = QApplication::widgetAt( _pos_click ) ;

        if(receiver == 0)
            printf("No element at the position (%d, %d)\n", x, y) ;
        else
        {
            QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            main_app->postEvent(receiver, event);
            QMouseEvent *release = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
            main_app->postEvent(receiver, release);
        }
    }
```

This way it is NOT working, even if the coordinates are good in my first printf. I never see the error "receiver == 0 ). If we modify the Qt library to add a log in the function PostEvent we see that x or y (randomly) equal 0 or 1 so that's why there is no click.

If I modify x and y this way (give a value to x / y ) it WORKS all the time :

```
void MainWindow::generate_click(int x, int y)
{

    x = 20 ;
    y = 80 ;

    printf("Enter generate_click : (%d/%d)\n", x, y) ;

    QPoint _pos_click( x, y ) ;
    QWidget *receiver = QApplication::widgetAt( _pos_click ) ;

    if(receiver == 0)
        printf("No element at the position (%d, %d)\n", x, y) ;
    else
    {
        QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
        main_app->postEvent(receiver, event);
        QMouseEvent *release = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
        main_app->postEvent(receiver, release);
    }
}
```

If I add an addition to the coordinate I receive, it also WORKS !

```
void MainWindow::generate_click(int x, int y)
{

    x = x + 5;
    y = y + 5;

    printf("Enter generate_click : (%d/%d)\n", x, y) ;

    QPoint _pos_click( x, y ) ;
    QWidget *receiver = QApplication::widgetAt( _pos_click ) ;

    if(receiver == 0)
        printf("No element at the position (%d, %d)\n", x, y) ;
    else
    {
        QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
        main_app->postEvent(receiver, event);
        QMouseEvent *release = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, receiver->mapFromGlobal(_pos_click), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
        main_app->postEvent(receiver, release);
    }
}
```

Even if the Qt documentation says that QPoint is expecting an integer, I think that the addition or the fact that we give fixed coordinates will cast them in a type expected by QPoint.

Are you able to tell me why the first example is not working ?

I hope my problem is clear and let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance.

Gaël

Comment: Check the value of `_pos_click.x()` and `_pos_click.y()` in each case.

Comment: @Holt it's what I have done :
`printf("coord : _pos_click(%d/%d, %d/%d)\n", x, _pos_click.x(), y, _pos_click.y()) ;`
And everything is perfect

Comment: Up, nobody has any ideas ? :)